# Rails: Error making get request to local server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New to ruby/rails, haven't been able to find a lot of resources and/or latest stack overflow threads on this topics so posting

I can see api/articles route when in command line when I try rails route, however, when trying to make a get request I am receiving the error

**ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] \"/api/articles\"**

Below are my relevant files.

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :articles, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

articles_controller.rb

```
module Api
    class ArticlesController  < ApplicationController
      def index
        articles  = Article.order('created_at DESC');
        render json: {
          status: 'success', message: 'loaded articles', data: articles
        },
        status: :ok
    end
end
```

Articles model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, presence :true
  validates :body, presence :true
end
```

full stacktrace:

```rb
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/api/articles"):

actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Is your ArticlesController right under the api folder within app (app/controllers/api/articles_controller.rb)?

Comment: yes it is, and application_controller.rb is on the same level as api folder

Comment: Can you share the structure of the app folder (maybe using tree).

Comment: here's a link to a ss, https://ibb.co/Qc2Yhgc

Comment: Did you restart the server after adding a new route? Try that, and see if it works.

Comment: If it's still not working (???!!!), try running `rake routes` to see what's been defined.

Comment: Are you missing an 'end' in your controller?